# PhoneGap: unable to getJSON from a remote server

Tags: android, json, cordova

Using PhoneGap 2.5.0 + jQuery 1.9.1 + jQueryMobile 1.3.0, I'm trying to download a remote JSON file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://foo.mydomain.com/json.php?callback=?",function(data) {
    alert("It works");
    })
});
```

I modified 'res/xml/config.xml' to allow remote accesses to my server:

```
<cordova>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> 
    <access origin="http://foo.mydomain.com*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's a problem related with Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue.

To solve this, you should use JSON-P in the ajax request.

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  url : 'your-external-url',
  data : {},
  success: function(obj){
  }
});
```